# Implementing Bluetooth LE Security

Tags: android, ios, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

We are working on a project of developing the soft and hardware for a bluetooth LE device.

We implemented GATT services and we are able to connect to the device.

Now the next step: Implement security.

We know that there are tree methods of security:

Just Works

Passkey Entry

Out Of Band

Since our device doesn't have a display (no_input, no_output), we are doomed to use Just Works since OOB is not supported by Android and iOS yet.

So this means we have this bluetooth device with all it's services just hanging there in the open to connect by anybody.

Is this really true in BLE?

We were thinking about implementing our own security just by connecting, writing a key to a keyservice and when that key is correct, the services open themselves for writing/reading. But what would that do with certification?

So you guys are our last resort since we are still hoping we are wrong in this one. Is there anybody who can acknowledge this fact? Or are we missing a big piece of the puzzle?

Answer (score 0):

You can implement Just Works, Passkey Entry and Out Of Band (NFC) on your BLE Device.
Passkey can be written on a label on the product or be hardcoded to 0000 or 1234 or whatever you choose. This works on iOS and Android if you implement correct Bluetooth Security configuration on your BLE Device. What chipset are you using?
Out of Band works fine on Android and Windows Phone with NFC. Maybe Apple iPhone 6 and 6+ will get proper NFC functionality in a more mature iOS version later. On iOS 8.1 it is still just for Apple Pay, not for industri standard NFC functionality.

First step is to set the GATT flags so your Service or Characteristic requires security.
Second step is to implement the bluetooth Security manager messages.
There are official white papers on this on BT Special Interest Group:
https://developer.bluetooth.org/DevelopmentResources/Pages/White-Papers.aspx

Comment: Following the bluetooth specifications, the only security model we are able to use is: Just Works. Since we don't have a display or a keyboard on our peripheral. So I guess we are forced to implement a service level security model?

Comment: All these security methods have been compromised somewhat by https://lacklustre.net/projects/crackle/ I commented this because you should consider this in your security efforts.